# How do I to configure the annotation [Authorize] to use Enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use `Enum` to annotation `[Authorize]`. I already configure but it still doesn't works, the security policies are allowing the access.

I do not created my `Enum` with numbers example: `Administrator = 1` or something like that, I just created using description as `Administrator, Manager, Common`. I would not to create numbers as index, just want to create by description as I shown.

How could I fix this ?

**Enum**

```
public enum RoleType{
    Administrator,
    Manager,
    Common
};
```

**AuthorizeAttribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PermissionFilter : AuthorizeAttribute{

    public RoleType Roles {get;set;}

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext){
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        //get the Session of User
        User user = httpContext.Session["User"] as User;
        RoleType role = user.role;

        if (((Roles & role) != role))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext){
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/accessDenied");
    }
}
```

**Method**

```
[PermissionFilter(Roles= RoleType.Manager)]
public ActionResult viewAllAdmin(int? pagina, String nome){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

I did

**AuthorizeAttribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PermissionFilter : AuthorizeAttribute{

    public RoleType[] Roles;

    public PermissionFilter(params RoleType[] roles){
        Roles = roles;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext){
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;
        try{
            Usuario usuario = httpContext.Session["Usuario"] as Usuario;
            RoleType role = usuario.role;
            Boolean contain = Roles.Contains<RoleType>((RoleType)role);
            Console.WriteLine("Contem Role: " + contain);

            if (!Roles.Contains<RoleType>((RoleType)role)){
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Debug.WriteLine("PermissionFilter AuthorizeCore: " + e.Message);
            return false;
        }       
    }


    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext){
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/acessoNegado");
    }
}
```

**Method**

```
[PermissionFilter(RoleType.Administrator, RoleType.Manager)]
public ActionResult viewAllAdmin(int? pagina, String nome){
}
```

And then, it works fine !

Comment: So you didn't need help from stackoverflow after all.